# kendo chart on windows mobile not able to scroll and tooltip hide issue

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova, kendo-ui

In phonegap app I am putting the kendo chart and when I scroll the screen then on windows phone kendo graph section is not allow me to scroll but I am able to scroll it on android and ios how to fix it?

and also same issue with kendo chart tooltip when I click on Bar then tooltip visible but when I removes my finger it goes only happens in windows mobile working fine on android and ios

any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI Mobile [doesn't support Windows Phone 7](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-02-06/kendo_ui_on_windows_phone.aspx), it requires [Windows Phone 8](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-02-25/kendo_ui_mobile_and_windows_phone_8.aspx) so I guess that's why you are experiencing weird issues.